# JAXBException caused by generated code

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jaxb, websphere

I am getting the following JAXBException of the form

> class SomeClass nor any of its super class is known to this context.

The full stack trace looks like this:

```
 javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.myCompany.generatedCode.WebServiceOperationName nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:586)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:130)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:364)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:185)
    at $Proxy41.deleteAccount(Unknown Source)
    at com.myCompany.myPackage.MyWebServiceClient.callSomeWebService(MyWebServiceClient.java:100)
(other classes specific to my application and framework)
...
Caused by: 
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.myCompany.generatedCode.WebServiceOperationName nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:452)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:314)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:243)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:75)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.marshal.MarshallerProxy.marshal(MarshallerProxy.java:100)
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext$1.run(JAXBDSContext.java:470)
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.marshalByElement(JAXBDSContext.java:455)
    at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.marshal(JAXBDSContext.java:414)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.impl.JAXBBlockImpl._outputFromBO(JAXBBlockImpl.java:189)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl.outputTo(BlockImpl.java:372)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl.serialize(BlockImpl.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:808)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:975)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:1016)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:271)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:233)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:1016)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMNodeImpl.java:488)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.writeMessage(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:3271)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.sendChunkedRequest(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:888)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.sendSOAPRequest(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:807)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.send(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPTransportSender.invoke(HTTPTransportSender.java:364)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:401)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:581)
    ... 52 more
```

What triggers this is attempting to make a call to a web service operation named `WebServiceOperationName`. I've seen other tips for dealing with this error which usually involve adding a `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation or making adjustments to how marshalling and unmarshalling are done.

In this case, I am calling a webservice whose code is generated by Maven based on a WSDL (and supporting schemas). I don't have direct control over the code produced by Maven, and I don't have control over the marshall/unmarshall calls. Other webservice calls in the application don't seem to be having any problem.

Even stranger, I can't reproduce this on my local server, though it happens on the development server. The generated JAR for the webservice is the same, as it the rest of the application's code.

This exception has appeared suddenly this week (and consistently), and I suspect that something has changed, environmentally, but I'm not sure what. Any ideas?

---

A new observation:

The first time I attempt to run this code on the server after it's been started/restarted, it takes a while (About a minute) before it fails and throws an exception. Every time after that, the exception is almost instantaneous...

---

Further information:

This problem is present in WebSphere 7.0.0.23 (which is on the server), but not in WebSphere 7.0.0.7 (on the workstation).

Comment: I had a similar error that @XmlSeeAlso was causing. If you aren't doing any type of inheritance, remove the annotation on the class in question.

Comment: @KevinMangold: I haven't added `@XmlSeeAlso`. The class that the error complains about is contained in a JAR that is generated from a WSDL. I peeked inside the jar and everything looks fine. I also suspect this is somehow environmental since the WSDL and the JAR haven't changed in quite a while. I'm not sure what to check next for this kind of problem.

Comment: Are you using the same versions of Java on development/local servers? If you are using the latest Java 7, I believe the version of JAXB has changed from earlier Java 7 versions.

Comment: @KevinMangold: I suppose that's possible that doing things like changing Java versions is usually a *major* deal around here, especially on DEV servers. I probably would have heard about it before it had a chance to happen, but maybe I'll go ask anyway...

Comment: You would think... I had no JAXB issues when I was on 1.7.0 (first version). However, now, under update 11, it is behaving differently. I dont recall what JAXB version it was using before but 2.4.2 does not work well for me. I need to manually use 2.2 or use older Java versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue's been resolved. I was inspecting the jar that contained the class WAS was complaining about and noticed that some of the classes were duplicated at different levels of package hierarchy. It's worth pointing out that the class that was reported in the original error was not actually one of these duplicated classes. Also, the application did not reference different variants of the same class - the classes referenced were in the expected package. The extra duplicates one level up were not referenced anywhere (as far as I can tell).

It *looked* like a bad Maven configuration, but when I inspected the xjb binding files, I couldn't figure out how the types in that schema namespace got bound to two different packages. Either way, I cleanded up some of the binding files used by Maven, refactored common bindings into one file, had Maven rebuild the jar, and then tested, and suddenly the issue was gone!

Clearly there was a problem in WAS 7.0.0.23 since the original jar worked fine on WAS 7.0.0.7. It *may* have been caused by a problem with the Maven bindings which resulted in a strange-looking but technically valid jar.

Also interesting: one of our developers upgraded WAS to 7.0.0.25 and used the original "bad" jar and got a "no such operation" error instead of the JAXBException.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in Guidewire ClaimCenter, which is an insurance application that can be configured but the core can't be modified at all, It's Java based it has component included like axis2 but I created a seperate java project that wraps a webservice call, I created all the stub code with wsimport. It works well under my deve enviroment which is windows and jetty because is the Guidewire platform to configure it (no other option). we use WAS 7 as production server.

```
    Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: au.com.mycompany.policyinquiry.retrieveinsurancepolicydetails.v1.RetrieveInsurancePolicyDetailsResp is not known to this context
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMinimalMethodMarshaller.demarshalResponse(DocLitBareMinimalMethodMarshaller.java:158)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:499)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:185)
    at $Proxy80.retrieveInsurancePolicyDetails(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to generate and compile the client in the server side just in case it was something related with different JDK platform, but that didn't solve the problem.
I found the next article [was 6](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PK75322)!
 but for WAS 6 , I haven't tried though.

```
    When the JAX-WS web service engine receives a message, it uses
    the JAXB engine to convert the message into java beans.
    The message indicates a failure occurred while converting xml
    into an object of type
    com.somecom.lib.business.xml.ComIdentifierXml.  The failure
    indicates that the JAXB engine was not initialized with
    information about this user class.
    .
    In this use case, the class
    com.somecom.lib.business.xml.ComIdentifierXml is packaged in a
    JAR at the EAR level. The exception does not happen if the
    class is packaged in a JAR located in the WAR module's
    WEB-INF/lib directory.
```

```
SOLUTION:
```

Target Environment:
IBM server
IBM JDK 1.6
IBM Webpshere 7.0.0.25

The client to call the webservice is using pure JAVA no dependency on external library JAX-WS RI 2.1.6

In webspehre
1- Set for the application the class loading to parent last
2- Turn off webservice annotations with this: Set the com.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine property to true. this will disabled Websphere own implementation based on a modified Axis2
3- Deploy your application with third-party JAX-WS runtime
in my case i used Glassfish Metro 1.5 which includes JAX-WS RI 2.1.7 and is the same as my local environment with JDK 1.6.0_37

That's it

Cheers
Alex :)

Comment: Thanks for the info anyway. We might try upgrading to WAS 7.0.0.25 to see if that resolves it. We've got GW's CC running here as well, I'll pass this on if any of them mention this problem.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I implemented a client to consume the webservice with JAX-WS RI (which is included in Java 6)and if you see the stack trace the error happens in axis2 library which I'm not using it, I guess that is the axis2 lib included in GW.

Comment: There's a way to disable WAS engine and use third party implementations see [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK96989)!

Comment: One of our developers upgraded WAS to 7.0.0.25 and used the original "bad" jar and got a "no such operation" error instead of the JAXBException. I did manage to fix the jar by tweaking the bindings for Maven.